# How to set specific time & minutes to datepicker?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, nsdatecomponents

I want to set specific time according to current time & datepicker time.

Like if user selects 3:01PM it goes directly to 3:30PM, 
3:20PM then 3:45PM,
3:35Pm then 4:00PM.
if 5:00PM then 5:15pm.

So user will be given options for time according to 3:00,3:15,3:30,3:45,4:00 and so on...

I have achieved this & when i go to 6:01Pm or any time in future than it works fine except i cant switch back to 5:01Pm (while current time is 3:00pm)

Any solution or possibility for it problem?

Try this below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datechanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}



 NSDate *date = [self.datePicker date];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];

if ([components minute] == 0)
    {

        [components setMinute:15];
    }
    else
    {
        NSInteger result =  (minute / 15);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            [components setMinute:30];
        }
        else if(result == 2  || result == 1)
        {
            [components setMinute:45];
        }
        else if (result == 3)
        {
            [components setMinute:60];
        }
    }


    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];

    [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:newDate];
    [self.datePicker reloadInputViews];
```

Comment: What is your exact problem??

Comment: Suppose it`s 4 pm now and i select time for 6:01PM then it goes to 6:30PM which is fine but if i switch it back to 5:01PM it should go to 5:30PM but UIControlEventValueChanged is being called on changed not after change so UIDatePicker takes it as 7:01PM instead of 5:01PM.

Try this code you will understand what i am saying.

Comment: You are setting up ` [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:newDate];` thats why It doesn't allow you to set time back to ` 5:01 PM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set you date changed method like this way, which allow user to set date back.

```
- (IBAction)datechanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
NSDate *date = [self.datePicker date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitHour |NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear) fromDate:date];

NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSLog(@"%li",(long)hour);

if ([components minute] == 0)
{

    [components setMinute:15];
}
else
{
    NSInteger result =  (minute / 15);

    if (result == 0)
    {
        [components setMinute:30];
    }
    else if(result == 2  || result == 1)
    {
        [components setMinute:45];
    }
    else if (result == 3)
    {
        [components setMinute:60];
    }
}

NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"%@",newDate);
//[self.datePicker setMinimumDate:newDate];
[self.datePicker setDate:newDate];
[self.datePicker reloadInputViews];
}
```

**Update 1**

You can set minimum date (means past time not allowed) in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datechanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

}
```

My this helps you,

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, but still i do not want to allow time that is past from current time which is not working with this...